# How to update Grafana password automatically using k8s Secret

Tags: grafana, kubernetes-secrets, argocd

I have Grafana deployed on the EKS.
The login password for Grafana comes from the AWS secret manager.
The first time Grafana is deployed, it fetches the secret from AWS secret manager, creates a k8s secret and uses the created k8s secret as the password.
As the value of the secret in AWS secret manager is updated the value of Grafana's k8s secret is also updated but the login password remains the same.

Explanation with an example:

- Secret value in AWS secret manager = **pass**
- When Grafana is deployed, grafana creates a k8s secret with data = **pass**
- login credentials for grafana is -> username:admin password:**pass**
- Secret value in AWS secret manager is updated to = **newpass**
- The Grafana's created k8s secret is being updated to = **newpass**
- But login credentials for grafana are still  -> username:admin password:**pass**

Comment: do you need to roll the grafana deployment; it may load the pass into memory on init, hence requiring a restart of the app

Comment: I tried to restart the Grafana deployment, but grafana is still using the old login password, and not the updated secret one.